# How can serialize a type that implemented IEnumerable with protobuf if it is in a list itself?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

As demonstrated by the following code, even with `IgnoreListHandling` set to `true` on the `TypeWithEnumerableInterface` `ProtoContract` attribute, it is still detected as a nested list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ProtoListHandling
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestTypeRegistration() //Passes
        {
            //Arrange
            var runtimeTypeModel = TypeModel.Create(); // Don't use the default run time model so the unit test has no side effects
            //Act + Assert
            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => runtimeTypeModel[typeof (ITypeInterface)].AddSubType(100, typeof (TypeHoldingOneInstance)));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestListTypeRegistration() //Fails
        {
            //Arrange
            var runtimeTypeModel = TypeModel.Create(); // Don't use the default run time model so the unit test has no side effects
            //Act + Assert
            //This test will fail.
            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => runtimeTypeModel[typeof(ITypeInterface)].AddSubType(100, typeof(TypeHoldingListOfInstances)));
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class TypeHoldingOneInstance : ITypeInterface
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public TypeWithEnumerableInterface Instance
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class TypeHoldingListOfInstances : ITypeInterface
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public List<TypeWithEnumerableInterface> Instances
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        [ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]
        class TypeWithEnumerableInterface : IEnumerable<double>
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public string ActuallyWantToSerializeThis { get; set; }

            public IEnumerator<double> GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }
        }

        interface ITypeInterface
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to persist this without needing to change the implementations of `TypeHoldingListOfInstances` or `TypeWithEnumerableInterface`?

Comment: If use inheritanse- you should protomemner +1: Instances must have ProtoMember equals 2.